# React avoidable re-rendering problem with AntDesign and PrimeReact

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-lifecycle, react-state-management, primereact

We are developing a huge application with React. One of our forms includes 60+ plus components placed on different Tab items.

When i try to edit an input it took 190ms to see typed chars in the textbox. After digging the problem for hours we realized adding a component increases the response time. Then we decided that the problem is antdesign s render logic. Then we tried it with PrimeReact using "why-did-you-update" package. The result was same!

When any change occurred in the state, all the components ( including Icons :) ) tried to render per "why-did-you-update" messages.

Here is the sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/6w30ro2l9w

Are the "why-did-you-update" messages wrong or we missing something?

Comment: did you manage to solve this? re-render happens even when i focus input, without changing any values